# How do you cast delete votes?

Tags: support

Among the [10k privileges](https://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) is the privilege to cast delete votes. I did a [search of meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+do+you+cast+delete+votes) and found lots of discussion of delete votes but nowhere is it made clear how to cast them. I thought it would just be a little button to click, similarly to close votes, but I see no button. Are delete votes made by notifying a moderator?

Using [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47118/how-to-calculate-bias-of-a-simulation) as an illustrative example, I would appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction. I suspect that the functionality only appears for 10k+ users.

**Edit:** I've noticed that, for example, on [this question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/i-think-there-should-be-more-of-an-effort-to-recruit-statisticians-for-this-webs), that there is a delete button. Both of the questions I linked to are closed, so why does one have a delete button while the other doesn't? Does the question need to be closed for a particular period of time before the delete option appears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first link (to [10K privileges](https://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools)) explains that "You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can vote for deletion."  It goes on to say that this waiting period is eliminated for "trusted users," which currently are those with 20K reputation.

Comment: Yes, I just read that, sorry for my sloppy reading of the page. I was just about to delete the question but I can't now that there's an answer. Please moderator-delete it (or not, if you think the question is useful). Thanks, @whuber.

Comment: I am glad you are interested in reviewing questions. I see no problem with keeping this thread open.